# Filling in Stewart's derivation of the arc length formula

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

To derive the formula for the arc length of a curve in 3 dimensions the approach Stewart takes is to estimate the length by summing the lengths of n subintervals. Then the actual length is assumed to be the the limit of this sum as $n\rightarrow \infty$. i.e.

$L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_1^n |P_{i-1}P_i|$

Assuming the curve is given by (f(t),g(t),h(t)) and everything is nice and continuous then using the mean value theorem on f,g,h we can express this as

$L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_1^n \sqrt{(f'(t_i*)^2 + g'(t_i**)^2 + h'(t_i***)^2} \Delta t$

where $t_i*,t_i**,t_i***$ came from the mean value theorem and are between $t_{i-1}$ and $t_i$ but need not be the same. This is a nice Riemann sum if all the $t_i$ stars are equal. Stewart just saws if f',g' and h' are continuous then this is limit is equivalent to that in which all the t stars are equal and he just leaves it at that.

How would one go about showing that this is indeed equivalent?